# How to customize Create Account page for the SignUp_SignIn Custom Policy in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I only want email address, first name, last name and password fields when a user wants to create an account.  I also want to disable the Send Verification Code button.  Where and how do I configure that page to only show those fields?  I'm using unified.html file from the Azure-AD-B2C-page-templates solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outputClaim reenterPassword, displayName in the `LocalAccountSignUpWithEmail` [technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-configure-user-input) and For disabling the email verification set the `EnforceEmailVerification` metadata to false.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-disable-email-verification#add-the-metadata-to-the-self-asserted-technical-profile) for more information.